# Tomcat 7 security - attempt to login?

Tags: security, tomcat

After deploying our app on Tomcat 7 we got lots of this:

```
<date> org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm authenticate
WARNING: An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "admin"
```

and in the access log we have found *lots* of this:

```
91.121.4.141 - - <date> "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 401 2486
```

that seems a france ISP (OVH SAS).

So.. what's going on? Are they try to log, ping? Is it a botnet?

How can we protect from this attempts to login?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That looks like a brute force attack against the Manager application. The LockoutRealm has done its job and locked the user to prevent the attack from being successful. However, it does mean the legitimate user won't be able to log in either. Assuming the attacks are coming from a single IP, block that IP as early as you can in your network and move on.

Comment: Thanks. I've ended up blocking the ip `iptables -A INPUT -s 91.121.4.141 -j DROP`

Comment: You might also consider something like fail2ban to prevent future similar attacks.

Comment: @Mark Thomas I am also having the same issue; I am seeing daily in the morning in Log file such lines. How to avoid it. Please suggest some thing. I am using Tomcat 7.

Comment: @Kumar My previous advice stands: block the source IP. The advice to use fail2ban to automate the process is good advice.

Comment: @MarkThomas Hey Mark, Could you please advise on tomcat configuration. I am getting connection refused error in Apache Jmeter while accessing my service url. How to increase no of request per seconds in tomcat 7.

Comment: If a load balancer is used then the access log file gives the ip of the load balancer that forwarded the request (and not the original ip of the attacker). Therefore, blocking the ip will block the load balancer that is forwarding your requests. Any tips on how to get the ip of the attacker for the case where you are using a load balancer?

Comment: Answer to my own question above: can get x-forwarded-for value:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve
Although I'm not sure attacker will contain this header.

Answer (score 1):

helpful information may be is here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/244614/is-it-normal-to-get-hundreds-of-break-in-attempts-per-day

and how to check (on CentOS/RedHat)
Failed

```
cat /var/log/secure | grep 'sshd.*Invalid'
```

Succeeded login attempts

```
cat /var/log/secure | grep 'sshd.*opened'
```

to block users which attempts every 15 seconds

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 15 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -m recent --set -j ACCEPT
```

and Full report about Auth

```
aureport
```

And additional tools info is here

http://www.tecmint.com/5-best-practices-to-secure-and-protect-ssh-server/

And some security technics is here

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH